# NGINX: How to add randomized headers to the responses

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I have a list of pre-defined header messages.

1st message is bla bla
2nd message is bla bla
3rd message is bla bla
4th message is bla bla
5th message is bla bla

I want to add a random one to the response every time. How can I achieve it? Thank you.

Comment: Your question is difficult to read. Perhaps you can write it to be more precise and more professional. I suspect the answer to your question will be that you'll need to call a script to generate random headers.

Comment: Try using the $request_time variable for that and do some regex checks to decide which header you'd like to send. It's not really randomized but maybe enough to fullfill your requirements without big effort.